# CRC-CCITT validation in java (android)

Tags: java, android, byte, crc

Hi
I have some data being received over a bluetooth connection.
The data has a 16-bit CRC 16-CCITT block which I want to use in order to verify that the data was transferred successfully and without error.
Is there any built in method in java or android that can help me or do I need to implement it myself? Will I need to encode the data and compare? I have a code snippet for doing that which I found online, but I'm not sure it is correct or efficient.
It is found at: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/51data/CRC16CCITT.java.html and the code is:

```
    int crc = 0xFFFF;          // initial value
    int polynomial = 0x1021;   // 0001 0000 0010 0001  (0, 5, 12) 

    // byte[] testBytes = "123456789".getBytes("ASCII");

    byte[] bytes = args[0].getBytes();

    for (byte b : bytes) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            boolean bit = ((b   >> (7-i) & 1) == 1);
            boolean c15 = ((crc >> 15    & 1) == 1);
            crc <<= 1;
            if (c15 ^ bit) crc ^= polynomial;
         }
    }

    crc &= 0xffff;
    System.out.println("CRC16-CCITT = " + Integer.toHexString(crc));
```

I also saw that Java has an implementation of crc32 at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html. Is that something I can use here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is very inefficient. There is a table-driven version around the Internet written originally in C in the 1980s that runs at least 8 times as fast. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) appears to provide some links.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree that this is inefficient, and I will consider changing it to be a more efficient solution using JNI but for now I still need to know what the JAVA solution is...

Comment: @ekatz I didn't say anything about using JNI. Just transliterate one of the existing C implementations, or find a Java implementation. It's only about 20 lines of code.

Comment: that was the point of the question - after looking for a java implementation, I arrived at this implementation which is, as you say, inefficient, I'm trying to see if there is anyone that has a better java implementation.

Comment: @ekatz that was the point of my answer and comments. It's not hard, I've done it many times over the years.